# Create a Password Entry Page that redirects to protected page

Tags: redirect, password-protection

I am in a pickle and need a solution asap.

I am creating an index page that will have a password form. When the user enters the given password it needs to redirect automatically to another page that is protected by that password.

I don't mind how this works, it could be that the index page is that password protected page, but I would like to be able to style my own password field and submit button.

Does anyone know of a quick and simple solution for this that is fairly secure?

Answer (score 0):

Well , the easiest way would be to first create a submit form in HTML with two fields (one for username, one for password or whatever you want)

Than, in the form code, redirect the form to a PHP script for the password etc,

the login script would use PHP sessions (google it) for creating a new user session and keeping track of logged in users etc
LOGIN FORM LIKE THIS:

```
         <table width="950" border="0">
  <tr>
  <td width="200" valign="top">LOGIN;</br>
   <form action="/actions/sessions.php" method="post">
            User:</br><input type="text" name="user" /></br>
Password:</br> <input type="text" name="password" id="password" /></br>
<input type="submit" />
</form></td>

  </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

THIS IS 'SESSIONS.PHP" SCRIPT called from HTML form THAT STARTS SESSIONS AND VERIFIES USER IN MYSQL DATABASE

```
<?php
// start the session //

session_start();
```

> 

Comment: That sounds brilliant. Do you know of any examples with working code? What is the best thing to google when searching for solutions? I can't find anything like this.

Comment: google for creating a login page with sessions and "PHP start session" and check my above script etc ---> I like this site  -->       http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Comment: Thank you for this code. I will use it as a basis of my search.

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for a quick solution I have purchased this which is ideal:

http://codecanyon.net/item/easy-file-protection-php/674633?sso?WT.ac=search_item&WT.seg_1=search_item&WT.z_author=NxtCode

Thanks to Ian for commenting though, much appreciated.